# Disable browser navigate back and forward scroll gesture

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, gesture

I am building a web app that has a horizontally scrollable canvas. While dragging items on this canvas and simultaneously scrolling using a 2-finger scroll gesture on a Trackpad, sometimes this triggers a browser back/forward. I'd like to disable this behaviour.

I know this behaviour can be disabled in System Preferences, however I need this change to be consistent on my application across anyone's desktop.

I've seen applications do exactly what I want - Google Slides for instance does not allow browser back/forward using the scroll gesture.

I also don't have the luxury of simply listening for scroll events and preventDefault() when the scroll positions are at the boundary. I have nested scroll containers which I have to support.

Comment: this is a hardware feature of certain devices that would be uncontrollable from a website.

Comment: But, like I said, Google Docs does control this. Using the scroll gesture for both browser navigation and scrolling doesn't make sense in a full edge-to-edge application with a scrollable canvas and widgets with content that can scroll as well.

Comment: do they handle the *gesture* or the ability to go back entirely? you do have some control over what the browser interprets as "navigation". i.e., a "back" command might go back to a previous state of the same page instead of returning to a previous page. is that what you're really trying to handle here?

Comment: Just tested google docs and it doesn't look like they disable this feature. Which application are you referencing specifically?

Comment: Oh I mean Google Slides! Updated my question. However, they simply preventDefault() on the scroll gesture. I need keep scrolling, but disable the page navigation gesture.

Comment: I have the same issue: I use a canvas and I cannot stop navigation when scrolling. So, how did this worked for you?